# Repeat 'where' clause on EF

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6.1

How do I make EF 'where' clause repeat something like:

```
var query = from p in db.Posts
            where p.Title == "title" && p.Author == "author"
            where p.Title == "title" && p.Author == "author"

            select p;
```

Now the title and author will of course come from a List object, something like:

```
List<string> authors = new List<string>(){ "author1", "author2", "author3" }
List<string> titles = new List<string>(){ "title1", "title2", title3" }
```

I can use Contains here but the requirement is to match both Title and Author accordingly. Since author & title are parameters I cannot just hard-code them and do a simple query

Sample SQL Query will be:

```
select * 
from Posts
where (title = "title1" AND author = "author1") OR
      (title = "title2" AND author = "author2") OR
      (title = "title3" AND author = "author3")
```

Comment: WHat exactly do you want to get as your query result?

Comment: Do you mean `where p.Title == "X" && p.Author == "Y" || p.Title == "P" && p.Author == "Q"`?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.  Could you please explain further what it is that you're actually after?  Nothing in the above appears to relate to entity framework at all.

Comment: I guess you need to use an 'or' i.e. || instead of your second use of 'where', although that would result in some crap code.

Comment: edited: added expected sql query. I'm using EF by the way so in case this will work as is on Linq-to-SQL I'll be happy to remove the tag for EF

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you actually want an && between the title and author, but || between each title/author combo. Supposing you have these:

```
Expression<Func<Post, bool>> where1 = p => p.Title == "title1" && p.Author == "author1";
Expression<Func<Post, bool>> where2 = p => p.Title == "title2" && p.Author == "author2";
```

If you create the following extension method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Combines two lambda expressions into a single expression.
    /// In the returned expression, the parameter in the second expression will be replaced
    /// with the parameter from the first.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The first expression to combine.</param>
    /// <param name="other">The second expression to combine.</param>
    /// <param name="combiner">
    /// How to combine the expression bodies.
    /// Example: <see cref="Expression.Or(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)"/>
    /// </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Expression<Func<T1, T2>> Combine<T1, T2>(
        this Expression<Func<T1, T2>> source,
        Expression<Func<T1, T2>> other,
        Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression> combiner)
    {
        var sourceParam = source.Parameters[0];
        var visitor = new ParameterReplacerVisitor(other.Parameters[0], sourceParam);
        var visitedOther = visitor.VisitAndConvert(other, "Combine");
        Require.That(visitedOther != null, () => "VisitAndConvert failed to return a value.");
        var newBody = combiner(source.Body, visitedOther.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2>>(newBody, sourceParam);
    }
```

... which uses the following `ParameterReplacerVisitor` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class replaces one parameter with another everywhere in a given expression tree.
/// This is handy when you have two lambda expressions that you want to combine into one.
/// </summary>
public class ParameterReplacerVisitor : System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _originalParameter;
    private readonly ParameterExpression _newParameter;

    public ParameterReplacerVisitor(ParameterExpression originalParameter, ParameterExpression newParameter)
    {
        _originalParameter = originalParameter;
        _newParameter = newParameter;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (node == _originalParameter)
        {
            node = _newParameter;
        }
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

... then you can combine these expressions like so:

```
var either = where1.Combine(where2, Expression.Or);
```

And then you can say:

```
var query = db.Posts.Where(either);
```

Comment: hmm, I'll try this one but I believe will produce sql which uses a sub-query instead of OR on the 'where' clause. Could you also tell me what is your expected query with the predicate above?

Comment: @gnaungayan: Why would it produce sub-queries? It's creating an expression equivalent to `p => (p.Title == "title1" && p.Author == "author1") || p.Title == "title2" && p.Author == "author2")`.

Answer (score 0):

First impression of your requirement is that you may need to do the `.Contains` to extract the records from your database, and then look at using [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) to filter down further from your parameters.